# Rounding up decimals in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am currently working on a project for work. Another dev and I built a webapp that displays some dispute amounts and such. The person I am working with chose ANTD for the ui visuals and tables to display information we needed for the website.

As we wrap up the project, I am tasked to do some menial things and do some touch ups on the project before it's done. We are parsing information from xlsx to json and spreading the data via props into a an ANTD table. , and I cannot find out for the life of me, how to round up the numbers to the right of decimal.

```
const importExcel = (file, addItem) => {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = event => {
    try {
      const { result } = event.target;
      const workbook = XLSX.read(result, { type: "binary" });
      for (const Sheet in workbook.Sheets) {
        // var XL_row_object =
        var sheetName = "";
        XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
        if (workbook.Sheets.hasOwnProperty(Sheet)) {
          const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(
            workbook.Sheets[Sheet]
          );

          data.forEach(x => {
            addItem(
              x.Invoice,
              x.Agreement,
              x.DM,
              x.SoldTo,
              x.Amount,
              x.Comment,
              x.Part,
              x.Part_1,
              x.Value,
              x.Total_Result
            );
          });
```

I am fairly new to programming and not sure how to go about this. I did some searching, and it seems react-pretty-numbers does what I need it to do, but cannot figure out how to apply it to what we already have. Any assistance or direction would be awesome !

Comment: Rounding has nothing to do with `React`, you can rely on the `Math` utils available in JS. `Math.round`.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what does "round up the numbers to the right of decimal." means? What is right? What is not working?

Comment: Sorry Dennis. New to a lot of this. Basically this: Value = 125.7888888888. I want to round the numbers to the right of the decimal to limit it to two digits.

Answer (score 5):

You can round up with `Math.ceil()`. There is also `Math.floor()` which rounds down and `Math.round()` which rounds to the nearest integer.

If you want to round to 2 decimal places you have to do something like `Math.round(numberYouWantToRound * 100)/100`

Comment: Thanks for the response Jlai! I appreciate it. The issue I am having here, is that the numbers I have to round are numbers that are parsed in the code from xlsx to json. Basically it's getting the excel file, parsing it from xlsx to a json array. So I don't have a specific number or numbers to round, but an array value. I would like to round every Value, Total_results, and Amount each time it's displayed in the table, if that makes sense. If it sounds confusing, it's because I'm confused =p. Appreciate it anyways!

Comment: You have to do this for every numeric value, e.g. `Math.round(x.Amount * 100) / 100`. I don't know which other properties in your data objects are numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add comments to previous answers as I do not have the reputation, nor do I have an correct answer to the question, besides `Math.ceil(value / valIncrement) * valIncrement`, value being the value you want to increment, and valIncrement, how much you want to increment (e.g. 0.25).

The reason why this is not the best answer is locales. What if my number is 0,5 ? Javascript will think I enumerated two numbers, when I actually introduced 0.5 but in a different language. So what is the correct procedure then ?